# C detecting endianess Example

Tags: c

I did not understand the example bellow given by some guy in another question about endianess detection.
The number set to "bint" should be 0x10203040 and not 0x01020304. Right?

```
int is_big_endian(void)
{
    union {
        uint32_t i;
        char c[4];
    } bint = {0x01020304};

    return bint.c[0] == 1; 
}
```

Comment: Endianess is only about *byte* order, not nibbles (or bits) in a byte.

Comment: As long as the testing is self-consistent (so the equality comparison matches what is in the initializer, all will be OK.

Comment: Bits inside a byte are always ordered in the same way?

Comment: Incidentally, using `union`s for type punning is not allowed by the standard; you should do something like `uint32_t i=0x01020304; return *((unsigned char *)&i)==1;`

Comment: _Bits inside a byte are always ordered in the same way?_ You can't tell the difference, period.  You know there are 8 bits in a byte (for almost all practical purposes), but you can tell nothing about how they're stored.

Answer (score 1):

On a big endian machine the bytes (not nibbles) in an integer are laid out in memory with the top byte of the integer at the lowest memory address so the layout of `c` on a big endian machine would be:

```
c[0] = 0x01;
c[1] = 0x02;
c[2] = 0x03;
c[3] = 0x04;
```

On a little endian machine the bytes are laid out in the opposite orders, with the lowest by of the integer at the lowest memory address.  So on a little endian machine `c` would be laid out as:

```
c[0] = 0x04;
c[1] = 0x03;
c[2] = 0x02;
c[3] = 0x01;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is little endian, the number will be stored as 04 02 03 01, while in big endian, it will be 01 02 03 04 . Note that when talking about endiannes, you talk about BYTE order, which in hexadecimal is 2 digits.

As this example may not be clear for you, let's take a better example: 0x12345678. 
In big endian, it is stored like 12 34 56 78, while in little endian is stored like 78 56 34 12.

Note that in my memory representation (like 01 02 03 04, for example), the adresses grow from left to right.